# iPhone: can I add Tableview in cell of another tableview?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have to create a UITableView. Suppose there are 2 table views TableView1 and TableView2. TableView2 will contain suppose 2 text boxes. And I have to add TableView2 in one cell of TableView1. Finally I have to access the values of text box from the inner TableView2 in the  TableView1.

I am new to iPhone development. In short I have to add a tableview to the cell of another tableview. I don't know whether this is possible. If it is, would someone please provide me some link or code to do it.

Comment: Have you tried it? What are you trying to do with this?

Answer (score 0):

This is not look good design. You can also use two text field in same cell and make it more in height also make a horizontal separator. also if you have only two textfields then make them global and declared as property.And add in a particular cell.

Read some tutorial for making custom cells and give some time to learning these tutorials.
See this [link](http://blog.webscale.co.in/?p=284) and by googling you can easily find more on this topic.

Comment: Thanks Ishu.But as of now i am not sure if my inner tableview will contain only 2 text boxes there may be many fields inside so i was just wanting to try out with a sample app and check if i can get the values of inner table view in the outer table view

Comment: This is not right design style. for such condition you make an entry in a table and by tapping that table you can show another table or switch the view which having the table.And show data accordingly.This way also supports your nesting and inner table view concept.

Comment: Ok Ishu. .i apprecite your answer.But can u pls tell me is it possible to do add one tableview in another tableview?And can i access the values of control in inner table view in outer table view?Just asking this for my knowledge.

Comment: don't think so, There is lot of problems: same delegate and datasource method use for inner table and outer table.So i think you need  to read apple design guidelines.find some thing here http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do. Of course, It is not good practice to do like this. Still you want then here is the trick to do that. 
Create Two ViewController and inherit them using UITableviewController say ViewController1 and ViewController2. 
Now in cell of Tableview1 add ViewController2 object. So Tableview2 would in Tableview1's cell. Now you need to handle inner tableview delegate & Datasource in Viewcontroller2. So you don't need to do lots of if.. else in same view controller.

Now you can take two textfield in Viewcontroller2.h file and assign cell's textField to that in cellForrowIndexPath method. So you can access both the textfield any time you want.

I know my answer is bit confusing but ask me any question if you have.

Comment: Thanks for the answer deepak.I will start trying this out by doing a sample code and will ask u if i need anything.You have mentioned some cellForrowIndexPath.I have no idea about this method.

Comment: Sure Any time. cellForRowAtIndexPath: is datasource method of UITableview. You must implement this in order to show anything in UITableviewCell. This is pretty simple. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Hi deepak.I have tried to add a TableView controller in cell of another table View controller.But its giving error if i try to add one table view to the cell of another table view.Any suggesstions?

Comment: How are you adding Tableview in cell ? Do you have Custom Cell or Can you share some code so I can get exact idea ?